# Python 3.7.3 Inadvertently Installed on Mac OS 10.15.1 - Included in Xcode Developer Tools 11.2 Now?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I decided yesterday to do a clean install of Mac OS (as in, erase my entire disk and reinstall the OS).

I am on a Macbook Air 2018. I did a clean install of Mac OS 10.15.1.
I did this clean install due my previous Python environment being very messy.
It was my hope that I could get everything reigned in and installed properly.

I've started reinstalling my old applications, and took care to make sure nothing was installed in a weird location.

However, when I started setting up VS Code, I noticed that my options for Python interpreters showed 4 options. They are as follows:

- Python 2.7.16 64-bit, located in `/usr/bin/python`
- Python 2.7.16 64-bit, located in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`
- Python 3.7.3 64-bit, located in `/user/bin/python`
- Python 3.7.3 64-bit, located in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3`

In terminal, if I enter `where python python3`
it returns 
`/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3`.

How in the world did python3 get there?

My only idea is that it now is included in the Xcode Developer Tools 11.2 package, as I did install that. I cannot find any documentation of this inclusion.

Any ideas how this got here? More importantly, how do I remove it? I want to use Homebrew for all of my installation needs. Also, why does VS Code show 4 options?

Thanks!

Comment: You say your previous Python environment got very messy. In the future, I would strongly recommend to work with virtual environments for specific tasks. They are easy to setup and tear down in case they become too cluttered, without affecting anything else on the system. For example using [pew](https://github.com/berdario/pew), which is a convenient wrapper around `virtualenv`. This way you can prevent this from happening again, and don't need to worry about this new Python 3 installation as your virtual environments are independent from it. (By the way, support for Python 2 ends this year.)

Comment: @Seb Yep, I will be using virtual environments from now on. I'm just amazed at how I have already seemed to have created a mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command line tool to run the python 2.7 environment is at /usr/bin/python, but the framework and dependencies for it are in /System. This includes the Python.app bundle, which is just a wrapper for scripts that need to run using the Mac's UI environment.
Although these files are separate executables, it's likely that they point to the same environment.

Every MacOS has these.

Catalina does indeed also include `/usr/bin/python3` by default. The first time you run it, the OS will want to download Xcode or the Command line tools to install the 'complete' python3. So these pair are also the same environment.

I don't think you can easily remove these, due to the security restrictions on system files in Catalina.

Interestingly, Big Sur still comes with python2 !

Comment: Thanks for the info! So, how would I go about updating python3 if it's installed by Catalina? I don't seem to have pip installed. Or, should I not really use these system installed installed versions, as they will be updated on Apple's schedule? And instead use Homebrew to manage everything?

Comment: I doubt Apple will update them: Catalina is the last to include any python, so they say. PErsonally, I just download the installer pkg from https://www.python.org/downloads/ 
That should include pip3.